# apt-mirror for Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Tags: ubuntu, mirroring, apt

I want to backup a full mirror of old-releases Ubuntu because I need Karmic packages for my software.  I'm also afraid that old-releases.ubuntu will be deleted.

Is there any possibility to get a full apt-mirror without changing sources.list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [apt-mirror website](http://apt-mirror.sourceforge.net/)

```
 sudo apt-get install apt-mirror
 vi /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

Add sources from `sources.list` and `sources.list.d` that you want mirrored.

Switch to apt-mirror user:

```
 # sudo su - apt-mirror
```

Run apt-mirror:

```
 $ apt-mirror
```

Uncomment line in `/etc/cron.d/apt-mirror` to run from cron.